# Asp.Net SignalR not working when Hosted in IIS behind a Load Balancer (Barracuda)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr, barracuda

In an ASP.NET Web Form application, we are using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR to update the progress of some long-running Task, its all working fine with local IIS server but it's not working when hosted in IIS behind load balancer (Barracuda)
Here is the Hub Code

```
  public static void SendProgress(string progressMessage, int progressCount, int totalItems,bool isInitializing)
        {
            //IN ORDER TO INVOKE SIGNALR FUNCTIONALITY DIRECTLY FROM SERVER SIDE WE MUST USE THIS
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
            var percentage =0.0;
            //CALCULATING PERCENTAGE BASED ON THE PARAMETERS SENT
            if (!isInitializing)
                percentage = ((double)(progressCount * 100) / (double)totalItems);

            if (Convert.ToDouble(percentage) > 100)
                percentage = 100;

            //PUSHING DATA TO ALL CLIENTS
            hubContext.Clients.All.AddProgress(progressMessage, Convert.ToDouble(percentage.ToString("N2")));
        }
```

Here is the Client-Side script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var progress = jqry.connection.progressHub;
            console.log("Test!!!!!!");
            console.log(progress);
            //var intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 250);
            progress.client.addProgress = function (message, percentage) {
                //at this point server side had send message and percentage back to the client
                //and then we handle progress bar any way we want it
                //Using a function in Helper.js file we show modal and display text and percentage 
                updateProgress(percentage);
                console.log("Signal R PERCENTAGE " + percentage);
            };

            //Before doing anything with our hub we must start it
            jqry.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                //getting the connection ID in case you want to display progress to the specific user
                //that started the process in the first place.            
                console.log("Signal R Done");
            });
        });
```

Initially Web socket was not enabled in load balancer so URL wws://www.example.com/signalR/ was giving 404 error but then we made changes to add

```
header
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
```

It's not giving the error and status is a success but it's not calling the Client-side function addProgress

We are not getting how to proceed on debugging the problem

**Update**
When we directly call SignalR endpoint(through Internal IP without Baraccuda)
still, it's not working, when we debug the web app

/Z1/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData= endpoint returns 200 OK
response is

{"Url":"/Z1/signalr","ConnectionToken":"sometoken","KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,"DisconnectTimeout":30.0,"ConnectionTimeout":110.0,"TryWebSockets":true,"ProtocolVersion":"1.5","TransportConnectTimeout":5.0,"LongPollDelay":0.0}

/Z1/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken= endpoint response returns 101 Switching Protocols

/Z1/signalr/start?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken= endpoint returns 200 OK
response is { "Response": "started" }

Comment: I suggest you could firstly try to enable the web socket in the barracuda according to this [link](https://campus.barracuda.com/product/webapplicationfirewall/doc/49054741/how-to-enable-websocket/1) and try to run your application again.

Comment: Hi @BrandoZhang We enabled Web Socket in Barracuda the same way mentioned in the link